# How to remove popup window when changing volume in XFCE

Tags: xfce

When I am changing sound volume in XFCE, it always shows this popup at the top right corner:

[image]

How to get rid of it and all the similar popups?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/104273/how-do-i-disable-pop-up-notifications-in-xubuntu

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks a lot. In slackware I ran: `removepkg /var/log/packages/xfce4-notifyd-0.2.2-i486-2` and it disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the popup in Slackware I ran:

```
removepkg /var/log/packages/xfce4-notifyd-0.2.2-i486-2
```